# Generally speaking, how are (Python) projects structured?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, structure

I'm a bit lost when it comes to structuring my project(s). I try to structure things in ways that make sense, but always end up restructuring the whole thing at least twice per day. Granted, my projects aren't very big, but I would love to not have to restructure everything and just settle on something for once.

I'll describe my current program to try to make sense of things. It's a graphical program with a database backend for calculating the price of sails. Not everything is written yet, but the user will be able to select a sail category and model from two dropdown menus. Depending on the category-model combination, the program will present checkboxes and spinboxes. These checkboxes and spinboxes, when changed, draw information from a database and present the price of having that checkbox checked or having a certain number (e.g., area in square metres) in the spinbox.

In its current form, the project looks like this:

```
COPYING
README.md
SailQt.pyw                    (Should program be called from here ...)
sailqt/
    __init__.py               (This holds a __version__ string)
    SailQt.pyw                (... or here?)
    gui/
        __init__.py
        MainWindow.py         (This needs access to a __version__ string)
        MainWindow_rc.py
        OptionsWidget.py
        ui_MainWindow.py
        ui_OptionsWidget.py
    resources/
        __init__.py
        database.db
        generate_gui.py
        MainWindow.ui
        MainWindow.qrc
        OptionsWidget.ui
        icons/
            logo.png
```

To further clarify. `resources` holds all `.ui` files made in Qt Designer. They are XML files that describe the GUI. They can be converted to Python scripts with a terminal tool, which I've embedded into `generate_gui.py`. The same goes for `.qrc` files. `generate_gui.py` places the autogenerated files in the `gui` folder with either prefix `ui_` or suffix `_rc`. `database.db` is currently empty, but will eventually be used to hold prices and everything.

`MainWindow.py` and `OptionsWidget.py` are Python files that hold objects of the same name, minus the `.py` suffix. `MainWindow` holds `OptionsWidget` in its display surface. Both objects use their corresponding `ui` and `rc` files.

`SailQt.pyw` is the file that makes a `MainWindow` instance, tells it to show itself, and then tells (Py)Qt to enter its loop and take over from there. It's basically much like a `.exe` file of a lot of graphical applications in that it's a small file that gets the program running.

My initial guess was to place `SailQt.pyw` inside the `sailqt` folder. But then `MainWindow.py` suddenly needed access to a `__version__` string. The only way I could figure out how to achieve that was to move `SailQt.pyw` to the root folder of my project, and to let `MainWindow.py` import `sailqt.__version__`. But considering that was the nth time I had to shuffle things around and redo lines in most files to account for that tiny shuffle, I decided to just ask here.

My questions are fairly clear:

- How are, in general, Python projects structured? [This pydoc link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) was helpful, but that seems more like a module to me than something that is actually executed by a user.
- Did I get the above structuring right?
- Bonus points for answering this, as it's a bit off-topic. How come I can do `import os` and then do stuff like `os.system("sudo rm -rf /")`, but I can't do stuff like `import sailqt` and then do `sailqt.gui.generate_gui.generate()`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Let's deal with your last question first, because it's the most important as far as structuring python projects is concerned. Once you've sorted out how to get the imports working correctly within your project, the rest becomes much easier to deal with.

The key thing to understand is that the directory of the currently running script is automatically added to the *start* of `sys.path`. So if you put your `main.py` script (what you're currently calling `SailQt.pyw`) *outside* of your package in a top-level container directory, it will guarantee that package imports will always work, no matter where the script is executed from.

So a minimal starting structure might look like this:

```
project/
    main.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        mainwindow.py
```

Now, because `main.py` must be *outside* of the top-level python package directory, it should contain only a minimal amout of code (just enough to get the program started). Given the above structure, that would mean not much more than this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    from package import app
    sys.exit(app.run())
```

The `app` module would contain most of the actual code necessary to initialize the program and set up the gui, which would be imported like this:

```
from package.mainwindow import MainWindow
```

and this same form of fully qualified import statement can be used from anywhere with the package. So, for example, with this slightly more complicated structure:

```
project/
    main.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        mainwindow.py
        utils.py
        dialogs/
            search.py
```

the `search` module could import a function from the `utils` module like this:

```
 from package.utils import myfunc
```

On the specific issue of accessing the `__version__` string: for a PyQt program, you could put the following at the top of the `app` module:

```
    QtGui.QApplication.setApplicationName('progname')      
    QtGui.QApplication.setApplicationVersion('0.1')
```

and then access the name/version later like this:

```
    name = QtGui.qApp.applicationName()
    version = QtGui.qApp.applicationVersion()
```

---

The other issues with your current structure are mainly to do with maintaining separation between code files and resource files.

Firstly: the package tree should only contain code files (i.e. python modules). The resource files belong in the project directory (i.e. outside the package). Secondly: files containing code generated *from* resources (e.g. by pyuic or pyrcc) should probably go in a separate sub-package (this also makes it easy for your version control tool to exclude them). This would result in an overall project structure like this:

```
project/
    db/
        database.db
    designer/
        mainwindow.ui
    icons/
        logo.png
    LICENSE
    Makefile
    resources.qrc
    main.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        mainwindow.py
        ui/
            __init__.py
            mainwindow_ui.py
            resources_rc.py
```

Here, the `Makefile` (or equivalent) is responsible for generating the ui/rc files, compiling the python modules, installing/uninstalling the program, etc. Resources needed by the program at runtime (such as the database file), will need to be installed in a standard location that your program knows how to find (e.g. something like `/usr/share/progname/database.db` on Linux). At installation-time, the `Makefile` will also need to generate an executable bash script (or equivalent) that knows where your program is and how to start it. That is, something like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

exec 'python' '/usr/share/progname/main.py' "$@"
```

which would obviously need to be installed as `/usr/bin/progname` (or whatever).

This may seem like quite a lot to deal with at first, but of course the major benefit of finding a project structure that works well, is that you can re-use it for all future projects (and start to develop your own templates and tools for setting up and managing those projects).

Comment: Thanks! That was an amazing answer. I've got the code reorganised fairly swiftly, as I was already halfway there. The project [can be found here](https://github.com/Rubykuby/SailQt). I've left the makefile behind for now, which I'll address someday. (And to be honest, I have no idea yet how to go around making makefiles). generate_gui.py retains some of its functionality for now.

Comment: What about tests directory and testing overall? I have great difficulty to incorporate testing using pytest into this structure. I assume `tests` directory should be on the same level as `package` and `main.py`, and should be run from the parent directory of `tests` with the command `pytest`. But how then is it possible to import for example `app.py` (or some module even deeper) in my test scripts?

Comment: @Devlige. Use exactly the same structure. Put both `test.py` and `tests` inside the top-level `project` directory. That will make them equivalent to `main.py` and `package`, and the imports will work in exactly the same way. Since `test.py` is in the same directory as `main.py`, it can import from both `tests` and `package`. And for the same reason, all the modules inside `tests` will be able to import from `package` (and *vice versa*, although that's not actually required).