# Python imports structure

Tags: python, structure, package

I want to have this structure for my project:

```
requirements.txt
README.md
.gitignore
project/
    __init__.py
    project.py
    core/
        __init__.py
        base.py
    engines/
        __init__.py
        engine1.py
        engine2.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        refine_data.py
        whatever.py
```

The application is run from `project/project.py`. However, I constantly get import errors when using relative or absolute imports.

Both engines need to import from `project.core.base`, the utils need to import from `project.core.base` as well, and `project.py` (the main file ran) needs to be able to import from `engines`.

Absolute imports don't work:

```
# engines/engine1.py
from project.core.base import MyBaseClass
```

which gives the error:

```
ImportError: No module named project.core.base
```

But if I try a relative import instead

```
# engines/engine1.py
from ..core.base import MyBaseClass
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

I've seen other projects on Github structured similarly, but this seems to cause all sorts of problems. How do I get this to work?

Comment: sibling packages should be able to just import from each other. so engines can just import core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use these imports:

engine1.py:

```
from core import base
```

refine_data.py:

```
from core import base
```

project.py

```
from engines import engine1
```

if you use pycharm mark *project* directory as sources root and then try to run project.py. If you don't use pycharm you can run project.py by going to *project* directory and running command:

```
python project.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your `sys.path`.  It's likely that the top `project` directory is in the python path, and it sees your sub-packages (ie. `utils`, `engines`, etc.) as separate packages, which is why it's giving you an error that you're trying to import from outside your package when doing relative imports, and absolute imports don't work because it can't find the top project directory because it's not under any of the python paths.

The directory **above** the top project directory is what needs to be added to the python path.

Ex.

```
/path/is/here/project/core/...

# Add this to the PYTHONPATH
/path/is/here
```

Comment: Should I just do a `sys.path.append()` within the script itself?

Comment: You certainly can do that.  Is your package meant to be distributed and installed?  If so, you should look into creating a `setup.py` script for your package and installing it, which make sure it is in the pythonpath

Comment: I'm just trying to run `project/project.py` from the command line. But I'll be sure to make a `setup.py` if I distribute it (I'll have to Google how, I don't know how to do it).

Comment: If you're running `project.py` directory, realize that you cannot do relative imports from there.  Also, currently, whenever you run a python file, it automatically adds the directory it's in to the python path.

Comment: @BobDylan See this answer for a better explanation of using a script to run your project and where to place it -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/22183108/5679120

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97905/discussion-between-patrick-carroll-and-bob-dylan).

Comment: Unfortunately my employer blocks chat.

Comment: ha, I just clicked on the link to see what it would do.  Didn't realize it would add a comment