# Unable to import module in same directory

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having an interesting problem dealing with importing modules in the same folder, which is a little baffling.

Here is a simplified representation of my project directory structure:

```
├── my_project/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── gui_class.py
│   ├── qt_files/
│   |   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── ui_file.py
│   │   ├── image_conversion.py
```

The issue: in my `main.py` file, I am instantiating a class from `gui_class.py` & calling a method from that class that runs `ui_file.py`. This file is converted from a Qt `.ui` file using `pyuic5` via PyQt5. **When I call the method that should create my window, I get an error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    import start_menu
  File "~/my_project/gui_class.py", line12, in <module>
    from qt_files.ui_file import Ui_File
  File "~/my_project/qt_files/ui_file.py", line 166, in <module>
    import image_conversion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image_conversion'
```

What am I missing here? The `image_conversion` module is a dependency of `ui_file.py`, and is without a doubt in the same directory as the UI file.

It's worth noting that nothing in `ui_file.py` should be changed. It is generated automatically and anything edited will be overwritten upon re-generation.

**UPDATE:**

The issue may actually be in how I'm importing the UI files in my `main.py` file.

```
from qt_files.ui_file import Ui_File
```

Is the problem I'm dealing with here how I'm trying to import my UI class? Please excuse my lack of experience with this kind of project management. Google showed me a lot of different answers, but none of them seemed to be straightforward.

** UPDATE 2:**

I tried to use [ekhumoro's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177976/generally-speaking-how-are-python-projects-structured) by stripping my project into a very minimal representation, and I'm still getting these errors.

```
├── noulsmatic_test
│   ├── designer
│   ├── icons
│   ├── noulsmatic.py
│   └── package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── start_menu.py
│       └── ui
│           ├── cchmc_logo_rc.py
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── ui_calibration.py
│           ├── ui_controlpanel.py
│           ├── ui_dataprocessing.py
│           ├── ui_savedialog.py
│           └── ui_startmenu.py
```

Simply, `noulsmatic.py` calls `start_menu.py` in order to set up a very basic, limited-functionality GUI with the 5 UI files in `ui`. However, the import lines in `start_menu.py` cause Pylint errors (`E0401`) and give me the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "noulsmatic.py", line 13, in <module>
    from package import start_menu
  File "/home/alex/Documents/CCHMC/noulsmatic_test/package/start_menu.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ui.ui_startmenu import Ui_StartMenu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'
```

Why am I still getting this error, even with `__init__.py` files and the same import style as in the linked example?

** UPDATE 3: **

I finally solved the import issue with my files in a subdirectory by adding the parent directory to the import line. Maybe I had just missed this in the resources I had read, including ekhumoro's example (linked above). However, I'm still having my original issue, which is importing my resource file.

At the end of each file in the `ui` package, there is the line `import cchmc_logo_rc` there to make sure the generated resource code is included in the GUI. It seems I can fix this by changing to `import package.ui.cchmc_logo_rc.py`. However, because it is code generated by `pyuic5`, I'd like to not have to change it. Is there anything I can do with my `__init__.py` file or something like that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does changing to `from . import image_converison` work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: You need `__init__` files in each folder to mark it as a package.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in your dirs?

Comment: Just blank `__init__.py`? I just added them; no change

Comment: @questionable_code. The linked question already explains how the imports should be done (although I have now added an extra example to make it even clearer). The issue with pyuic resource module imports can easily be solved by using the `--from-imports` or `--import-from` options. Run `pyuic --help` to see a full list of options.

Comment: I'll look at this once I'm home. I deleted my other question. Thanks for your attention.